# Using gradle in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm trying to use gradle in Eclipse. 
Here's what I did, I installed "Gradle Integration for Eclipse" and "Buildship Gradle Integration".

After that I tried importing my project like so:

[image]

But my project now only exists out of some generated files, not my actual project...

[image]

All I want is have Gradle import the libs for me. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Your screenshot says that it is about creating a "new" project. So you maybe used the wrong wizard.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed pressed "New project" instead of "Import", import works :) It's odd that java projects can be imported using the new option, it's why I got into the habit in the first place.